# Error "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined"

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-fullstack

See the output and the codes of the files:

[image: output]

[image: code]

[image: code of App.js]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal in your project's root directory (where your package.json file is located) and run the following commands:

Shell:

With NPM

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --force
```

Only if you use @mui/icons-material

```
npm install @mui/icons-material --force
```

Only if you use @mui/lab

```
npm install @mui/lab --force
```

---

With YARN

```
yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Only if you use @mui/icons-material

```
yarn add @mui/icons-material
```

Only if you use @mui/lab

```
yarn add @mui/lab
```

If you get an error while installing the packages, add the --force flag at the end.

The command will add the @mui/material package to the dependencies of your project.

If you use the @`mui/icons-material and @mui/lab` packages, make sure to install them as well as per the instructions above.

Comment: its not working

Comment: @AkashSharma: please try to add a complete and substantial fault report in the comments, so this answer author can help you. If you can think of "it's not working" as the least helpful fault report possible, that will serve you very well generally.